# Freemarker: strip newlines but do NOT compress whitespace?

Tags: java, freemarker

Is there an easy way to strip newlines but **not** compress whitespace?

The [`<@compress>` directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html#autoid_28) does both, which is not what I want.

I have a section in a loop like this:

```
<#list items as item>
 * <#if something>${something?right_pad(10)}<#else>${something_else?right_pad(10)}</#if><#if another_thing>${more_data?right_pad(20)}<#else>${even_more_data?right_pad(20)}</#if>
</#list>
```

which makes for some really long lines, and I would greatly prefer doing something like:

```
<#list items as item>
 * <#if something>
       ${something?right_pad(10)}
   <#else>
       ${something_else?right_pad(10)}
   </#if>
   <#if another_thing>
       ${more_data?right_pad(20)}
   <#else>
       ${even_more_data?right_pad(20)}
   </#if>
</#list>
```

but it appears there isn't an easy way to disambiguate the spacing here given for clarity, with the spacing I want to output using `right_pad`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1) Use commented out white spaces:

```
<#list items as item>
 * <#if something><#--
       -->${something?right_pad(10)}<#--
   --><#else><#--
       ${something_else?right_pad(10)}<#--
   --></#if><#--
   --><#if another_thing><#--
       -->${more_data?right_pad(20)}<#--
   --><#else><#--
       -->${even_more_data?right_pad(20)}<#--
   --></#if>
</#list>
```

2) Use <#lt> (left trim for current line WITHOUT new line symbol) or/and <#rt> (right trim for current line WITH new line symbol)

```
<#list items as item>
 * <#if something><#rt>
       ${something?right_pad(10)}<#lt><#rt>
   <#else><#lt><#rt>
       ${something_else?right_pad(10)}<#lt><#rt>
   </#if><#lt><#rt>
   <#if another_thing><#lt><#rt>
       ${more_data?right_pad(20)}<#lt><#rt>
   <#else><#lt><#rt>
       ${even_more_data?right_pad(20)}<#lt><#rt>
   </#if><#lt>
</#list>
```

Check this for details: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html

Comment: bleah! :-( Thanks for showing me passable ways to do this. Are there better templating libraries for Java? I feel icky when I get into things like this. I wish there were a Java port for Python's jinja2 library.

Comment: icky perhaps but gold when needed